# I cant edit the style of my javascript link

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

I have a conditional statement that creates a link in an empty id tag (`#demo`)
The link appears fine on the page when the conditions are met but I am unable to edit it using CSS.

I have tried setting an `<a>` tag and doing this in CSS:

```
a{
  text-decoration-none;
}
```

I have tried the same for the id (`#demo`).  I think the issue is that the element does not exist in the standard HTML, only in the JavaScript.  Any ideas?

```
let zone10btitle="Zone 10b";
let zone10blink =zone10btitle.link("zones/zone10b.html");

if(c10b.includes(acodevalue)==true || 
c10bcities.includes(acodevalue)==true){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=zone10blink;
 }
```

Comment: Are using a library, framework, or plugin? I don't recognize `.link()` method.

Comment: It is not quite a standard but there https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp

Answer (score 1):

`link()` is not part of the standard but should be supported by all common browsers [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp)

It returns a string embedded in an `<a>` tag, so your CSS should match the generated link.

Your CSS rule needs to be `a {text-decoration: none;}` though, so if what you wrote in your answer is not a typo, you got your mistake: `a{ text-decoration-none; }` is invalid CSS.

CSS Rules need to be in the form of `<selector> { <property>: <value>}` with appropriate subsitutes for `<selector>`, `<property>` and `<value>`.

Btw, going for the id `demo` would affect the parent of the link, not the link itself, as you set the **innerHTML** of the parent to be the link.

In this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp) you also have an example code you can run very similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can find similar code snippet here and it styles the a link. Not sure if you are using inline styling or external css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a{
text-decoration: none}
</head>
</style>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a string as a hyperlink.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
  var result = str.link("https://www.w3schools.com");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Credit: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_str_link

Comment: thank you this worked.  I'm not sure why it didnt work when did this on an external styelsheet but for some reason it works for internal.  thanks